# value stored in the structure changes

Tags: c

I am writing a program for program blocks in system software. I stored each line of assembly program into an array. Later I seperated them into tokens and stored them into a structure. But i don't know why at the end `intfile.oper[0]` is being replaced by `intfile.oper[m]`

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<fcntl.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<sys/stat.h>
struct intermediate_file
{
    char line[50][50]; 
    char filename[20];
    char instr[20][10];
    char label[20][10];
    char oper[30][10];
}intfile;
char buffer[2000]=" ";
char statement[50][50]; /*to store each line of the input program*/
int i=0;/* to count no of lines*/
void read_into_buffer()
{
    int fd;
    fd=open("input.txt",O_RDONLY);
    const ssize_t r=read(fd,buffer,500);
    buffer[r]='\0';
    printf("\nTHE FILE CONTENTS ARE:\n%s",buffer);
}
void into_statements()
{

    char *tok;
    int j;
    tok=strtok(buffer,"\n");
    while(tok !=NULL)
    {
        strcpy(intfile.line[i],tok);
        strcpy(statement[i],tok);
        i++;
        tok=strtok(NULL,"\n");
    }
}
void seperation()
{
    int m,count;
    char *tok;
    /*extracting first statement into the structure*/
    sscanf(statement[0],"%s %s %s",intfile.filename,intfile.instr[0],intfile.oper[0]);
    for(m=1;m<i;m++)
    {
        printf("\nm:%d",m);
        /*counting the no of tokens in each line*/
        count=0;
        tok=strtok(statement[m],"  ");
        while(tok!=NULL)
        { 
            count++;
            tok=strtok(NULL,"  ");
        }
        /*extracting into the structure*/
        if(count==3)
        {
            sscanf(intfile.line[m],"%s %s %s",intfile.label[m],intfile.instr[m],intfile.oper[m]);
            printf("\n%s",intfile.oper[0]);
        }
        else//if count==2
        {
            sscanf(intfile.line[m],"%s %s",intfile.instr[m],intfile.oper[m]);
            printf("\n%s",intfile.oper[0]);
        }
     }
 }
int main()
{
    read_into_buffer();
    into_statements();
    seperation();

}
```

input.txt contains:

```
COPY   START 0000
FIRST  STL   RETADR
CLOOP  JSUB  RDREC
       LDA   LENGTH
       COMP  #0
       JEQ   ENDFIL
       JSUB  WRREC
       J     CLOOP
ENDFIL LDA   =C'EOF'
       STA   BUFFER
       LDA   #3
       STA   LENGTH
       JSUB  WRREC
       J     @RETADR
       USE   CDATA
RETADR RESW  1
LENGTH RESW  1
       USE   CBLKS
BUFFER RESB  4096
BUFEND EQU   *
MAXLEN EQU   BUFEND-BUFFER
```

I am getting `MAXLEN` instead of `0000` for the last `m` value

```
i.e

m:19

0000

m:20

MAXLEN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You are *reading* `intfile.oper[m]` with the `sscanf` functions, but then you **print** `intfile.oper[0]`.</s>

```
if(count==3)
{
    sscanf(intfile.line[m],"%s %s %s",intfile.label[m],intfile.instr[m],intfile.oper[m]);
    printf("label %s, instr %s, oper %s\n",intfile.label[m],intfile.instr[m],intfile.oper[m]);
}
else//if count==2
{
    sscanf(intfile.line[m],"%s %s",intfile.instr[m],intfile.oper[m]);
    printf("instr %s, oper %s\n",intfile.instr[m],intfile.oper[m]);
}
```

The reason the last operand `MAXLEN` overwrites the *first* operand is **Because Of Overflow**. Your file contains **21** text lines, not 20. Your static array can only story 20 values, *numbered* `0` up to `19`, as C arrays are zero-based.

A new fix:

```
char instr[21][10];
char label[21][10];
```

---

Unrelated to the issue, but if you are thinking of using the results from this scan elsewhere, you might want to make sure the `label[m]` elements are all set to `NULL`. As it is, they have either the value read with `sscanf` *or* they contain something entirely random. How would you know if the value is legit?

Also, please take a look into *dynamic memory allocation* with the functions `malloc` and `free`. First, you don't need to create an array that is "hopefully" large enough for your document (then you would not have had this particular issue), but secondly, the same may happen with your *strings*.
Currently, as soon as a single 'label', 'instruction', or 'operand' is longer than **9** characters (not "10"!) you will run in to problems.

Comment: just print the value of intfile.oper before and after the for loop 0000 is replaced by MAXLEN

Comment: i gave printf statement after ssanf to show that the `intfile.oper` value remains the same for every value of m except the last m.